# Push a UITableView modally as a 'transparent layer above' my current View

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios9

I need your help.

I want to push a UITableView modally as a 'transparent layer above' my current View.

The TableView exists already and I want to reuse it in a slightly different context.

So the User creates a new Object inside the View, he gives it a name and a description and a topic, when he does so I want to show all existing topics(the TableView) and pick one, then the TableView should disappear.
All its functionality is exactly like usual and it isn't allowed to cover the NavigationBar.

So my Question: is that possible and how?

I hope I could make myself understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to present a tableviewcontroller which will be transparent over your view controller, it is possible .
Create your tableviewcontroller instance and before presenting the viewcontroller add the following code.

`tableVC.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
        tableVC.definesPresentationContext = YES;
        [tableVC setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];`

In your tableVC set backgroundcolor to clearcolor It might work